# Version of Qt Creator in Ubuntu Touch SDK

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have followed the instructions on go mobile to set up for Ubuntu Touch Development and I have a question about the Qt Creator.

In the description of the SDK on http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/02/releasing-the-ubuntu-touch-developer-preview-and-sdk-alpha/, it says they are using Qt Creator 2.7. After following the instructions on Go Mobile, I ran Qt Creator and checked the version. It says 2.6.82. However, when checking in the Ubuntu Software Center it says that I have Qt Creator 2.7 installed.

Do I have both installed and I am just running the wrong thing? Or is something displaying the wrong version?

It's worth noting that I was able to follow the instructions for developing the CurrencyConverter and it worked ok. I just want to know if I am really supposed to be running 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why that is. I am getting the same version number, but I know this is the right version of Qt Creator, because I had the SDK preview installed, and once they released the SDK alpha, Qt Creator recieved updates and now has the Welcome tab with the Ubuntu symbol. So no, you don't have two versions installed, that one is the right one, as you can tell by the Ubuntu symbol.

[image]

Comment: what desktop environment is that, out of curiosity?

Comment: @strugee It's Unity with the launcher set to auto-hide. The theme is Elementaryish with the Faience-Azur icon theme.

Comment: thanks for explaining; I got confused by the bar at the left - I didn't look closely enough and didn't realize it was part of Qt, I thought it was a dock!

Comment: thanks for the response iBeleive. Glad to know I'm not the only one and that I am in fact running the right version.

Answer (score 2):

Qt Creator 2.7 is not released yet.

It is in the beta phase.
That is why you see 2.6.82 as the version number.